# Creating a Type object corresponding to a generic type

Tags: java, generics

In Java, how can I construct a `Type` object for `Map<String, String>`?

```
System.out.println(Map<String, String>.class);
```

doesn't compile. One workaround I can think of is

```
Map<String, String> dummy() { throw new Error(); }
Type mapStringString = Class.forName("ThisClass").getMethod("dummy", null).getGenericReturnType();
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: you need to make dummy public for the hack to work.

Comment: What do you need this information for, after all? If you elaborate that, better answers may be given.

Comment: @aioobe If it's the same class, then `private` is fine. `ThisClass.class` or `getClass()` would have been better than using `Class.forName`.

Comment: I have many automatically generated interfaces, where some methods take a `Map<String, String>` parameter, and those methods are the ones I don't care about.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline That's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: Don't bother with Type. Use classmate to construct a "GenericType" that makes the type information fully accessible at runtime. See https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-classmate. Your code would become:

`new GenericType<Map<String,String>>() {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public Map<String, String> dummy;
    public static void main(String... args) throws SecurityException, 
                                                   NoSuchFieldException {
        Type mapStringString = Test.class.getField("dummy").getGenericType();
        // ...
```

Is a *slightly* less ugly hack..

---

As Tom Hawtin suggests, you could implement the methods yourself:

```
Type mapStrStr2 = new ParameterizedType() {
    public Type getRawType() {
        return Map.class;
    }
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] { String.class, String.class };
    }
};
```

returns the same values as the other approach for the methods declared in `ParameterizedType`. The result of the first approach even `.equals` this type. (However, this approach does not override toString, equals and so on, so depending on your needs, the first approach might still be better.)

Comment: declaring dummy static final would be even lesser uglier :)

Answer (score 2):

It's all done with interfaces, so you can construct your own implementation.

However, the easiest way is to use reflection on a dummy class created for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the correct and the only way to get the *generics* at runtime. The type is erased ("type erasure"), the *Bytecode-Map* is actualy an Object-to-Object Map, the generics defintion in the source code are only used by the compiler to assure type safety.

Comment: The original poster is asking for `Type` not `Class`.

Comment: Everything about `Map<String, String>.class` is known at the compile-time, so there is no reason that shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Alexey The trouble is `Map<String,String>.class` makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.