# Creating parameterized type object using anonymous class

Tags: java, generics

This might be a stupid question, but I just saw a question asking [how to create a Type variable for a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989055/creating-a-type-object-corresponding-to-a-generic-type). The consensus seemed to be that you should have a dummy method returning that type, and then use reflection to get it (in this case he wanted `Map<String, String>`). Something like this :

```
public Map<String, String> dummy() { throw new Error(); }

Type mapStringString = Class.forName("ThisClass").getMethod("dummy").getGenericReturnType();
```

My question is, not having used reflection that much, couldn't you just do something like:

```
Type mapStringString = new ParameterizedType() {
    public Type getRawType() {
        return Map.class;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] { String.class, String.class };
    }
};
```

Would this work? If not, why not? And what are some of the dangers/problems if it does (besides being able to return some Type like `Integer<String>` which is obviously not possible.

Comment: I'm trying to do what your proposed solution allows: get a Parameterized Type from a raw Type and list of Type parameters supplied at compile time. Did you find another way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you could, and for most applications it would probably be sufficient.

However, using the first method, you get a more refined object. Let's say for instance that you create an object `type1` using the first method, and `type2` using the second method. Then `type1.equals(type2)` would return true (since the first method returns an object that properly implements the equals-method) but `type2.equals(type1)` would return false (since in the second method, you haven't overridden the equals-method, and are using the implementation from `Object`).

Same reasoning applies to other (sometimes useful methods) such as `toString`, `hashCode` etc. The second method does not provide useful implementations of these.

Comment: Actually type1's (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl) implementation  of equals seems to cast the parameter of equals to ParameterizedType and then use the interface methods to compare the classes, so `type1.equals(type2)` would return true, though the opposite (`type2.equals(type1)`) would return false; you could implement those as well, but then the code gets a little chunky

Comment: Sure. You could get the same result in method 2 as in method 1, but it requires some more work, as you have noticed.

Answer (score 7):

If you include Google's [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library in your project (you should; it's great), use its [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) to get a type. Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library (for interacting with JSON) has a similar [version](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html). Both are used like this (to get a `Type` representing `List<String>`:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
```

If you don't want to rely on any third-party libraries, you can still use anonymous types to get a generic *concrete* type with one line of code (this technique will not work with interfaces and could be more trouble than it's worth for Abstract Types). To get a `Type` representing `HashMap<String, String>`, do this:

```
Type t = new HashMap<String, String>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

I have verified that resulting `Type` instance `.equals()` the `Type` instances created by [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)'s [`TypeToken`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html), though have not verified the same for [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s version of [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which I do not have access to at the moment. (Guava is a more general-purpose library that is so handy for all sorts of things, you should probably be using it anyways.)

Comment: This still requires that List<String> is known at compile time. In the OP, the raw type and parameter types were not know until compile type.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the mentioned libs from Google there is also a lib from Apache that does the job.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.TypeUtils;
...
ParameterizedType type = TypeUtils.parameterize(List.class, Double.class);
...
```

Finde code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.java) and Maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3).

Comment: And it does its job without incorporating new empty anonymous class into your compiled codebase. Handy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the simplest way (== least code) to do this would be a dummy interface extending the type your interested in, and then [`getGenericInterfaces()[0]`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29) from its class (use [`getGenericSuperclass()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29) if you're interested in a class):

```
private interface MapStringString extends Map<String, String> {}
private static ParameterizedType mapStringString(){
    return (ParameterizedType) MapStringString.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
}
```

It doen't scale well, though, as you have to create a new class for every `ParameterizedType` you want to represent. I don't see why your implementation wouldn't do (unless there are narrowing casts somewhere), and it does have the appealing benefit that you can make it reusable.

Comment: While this seems as 'hackish' as the first method I gave, it at least gives better looking code where you try to get the type (just calling the function instead of doing get class, then get method, then get generic return type each time you want to use it).