# Given a ParameterizedType and a Type, how can I reparameterize the first type?

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have a `Type a` which is a `java.util.TreeSet<T>`, having been parameterized via a generic we can't see due to type erasure. We also have a `Type b`, which is a 'java.lang.Integer'. How do I construct a `ParameterizedType` that is a `java.util.TreeSet<java.lang.Integer>`?

Alternatively, if it's any easier, we could have a raw `java.util.TreeSet` type to work with.

Comment: The question is what you want to do with the Type and ParameterizedType objects. In principle, you get those via reflection on the corresponding objects.

Comment: I don't care at all about the plain `Type` object. I need the `ParameterizedType` to pass to gson to deserialize the collection.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989475/creating-parameterized-type-object-using-annonymous-class

Comment: Not quite. In that case, both types are set at compile time. In my case, neither are. I actually found that question before posting mine.

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer with how? I re-read the answers and don't see the applicability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `ParameterizedType` like so:

```
public class MyParamType implements ParameterizedType {
  private Type rawType;
  private List<Type> paramTypes;

  public MyParamType( Type raw ) {
    this.rawType = raw;
  }

  public void addParamType( Type t ) {
    paramTypes.add(t);
  }

  //for the interface methods, just return what you stored before
}
```

Do more or less the same for `Type`.
If you need more hints for what `Type` should actually implement for non-generic types (it's only a marker interface), look at the JDK source or look at a concrete instance in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You gave half of the answer to your own question. The type parameter (Integer in your case) is an erasure existing at compile time only. So, if you want to create `Set<Integer>` while you are developing your code you just can say:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

or if you are lucky Java 7 user even shorter:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new TreeSet<>();
```

However this line will be compiled to plain code:

```
Set myset = new TreeSet();
```

So, if you want to create instance of `TreeSet<Integer>` at runtime you just have to create instance of plain `TreeSet`, e.g.  `Class.forName(className).newInstance()`. Type parameter `Integer` is irrelevant in this case.

EDIT:
I just have read your comment and understood why are you asking. If you really want you can create subclass of `TreeSet` : `class IntegerTreeSet extends TreeSet<Integer>`. The parameter type of `IntegerTreeSet` can be discovered using reflection API.

This class can be either created statically (just write this in your code) or dynamically using tools like Javassist or CGLIB.

Comment: I don't actually want to instantiate it -- I just want a Type object describing it.

Comment: Regarding your edit, my choice of Integer and TreeSet were arbitrary. The `ParameterizedType` can describe any collection, and the `Type` can describe any object.